# (iOS) Multiple notifications via locationManager:didExitRegion: when exiting a region

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-location

I'm working on a location-based app that makes use of the CLLocationManager region monitoring.

I'm using a single CLLocationManager and single delegate (which are set up in the main app delegate at startup), and I'm noticing that I often get a burst of multiple calls to my delegate (on locationManager:didExitRegion:) when exiting a monitored region -- usually two calls, but sometimes more. Has anyone else experienced this, or have any ideas what can be going wrong?

I'm instantiating the CLLocationManager as follows, in a class that is instantiated in the app delegate:

```
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
```

I'm setting up region monitoring like this:

```
    // The region instance has a radius of 300 meters
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:1000];
```

As I understand from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125), providing the desired accuracy of 1000 means that locationManager:didExitRegion: should only be called once we're 1000 meters outside of the region.

On additional point -- as far as I've seen, I only get a burst multiple notifications if I'm in the car (and therefore travelling quite quickly). It doesn't seem to happen if I'm on a bike or on foot. Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong (or if this is an issue that others have already encountered) are appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, you can simulate your location on the simulator. You can even simulate travel paths. No need to drive around with your car^^

Comment: https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator enables you to load Google Earth KML route files into simulator :)

Comment: About simulating the location, yep, I know that works, but region monitoring on the simulator is much different on the simulator than on real hardware due to the use of cell towers, etc on the hardware. I already do most testing on the simulator, but some issues (like the one above) can only really be tested on the hardware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr: It's really quite simple - you're getting as much information as Apple can give you about the fact that you're crossing cell tower boundaries - meaning, not really good data at all.

Now the real story:

Generally, there are only a couple of ways that CoreLocation can determine one's position:

- By GPS. This is highly accurate (tens of meters), but takes lots of power to use.
- By WiFi. This is *generally* accurate, though wifi base stations can and do change, which makes it fuzzy. This method cross-references the wifi stations in the area vs some known accurate locations - so it knows when it sees "FooWifiStation" that it's associated with a particular area, measured by precise instruments, or perhaps even other phones with GPS turned on (which is controversial, we may never know if Apple uses this method)
- By cell tower locations. These don't move, so it knows you're within a big fuzzy dot of coverage when you're associated with a tower. This is the least accurate, but least power-consuming, because your phone is *already* doing the work to stay in contact.

You can even see this if you go into the maps application "cold": you start out immediately with a big fuzzy blue dot, (at least 1km where I am), then it shrinks as it gets a wifi location fix, then it more or less disappears when GPS gets its fix. It's doing [cell tower] => [wifi] => [gps] accuracies in real time.

From my experience, the "significant location change" clause means "We'll let you know whenever you move in a big way, *as long as we don't have to do any more work or expend any more power to get you that data*. This means de facto that the very best you can rely on is using transitions between cell towers. Apple deliberately left this vague, because if another app uses something that has better resolution - say, you open Maps.app, and it gets a GPS fix - it is possible that you will suddenly get a *great* fix on location, but you can't depend on that always being the case. You've asked for a "weak reference" to location.

Now think about what happens when you are wandering about in your car: your cell phone has to manage that transition. It gets handed off, talks to multiple towers at once, that sort of thing, to manage a seamless transition which must be viable *while you are having a conversation*. Just that is a pretty neat feat for any little box to do. Necessarily, this will cause you to see a bit of bounce in location updates, because, to the phone, you're vibrating between cell towers at this time as it negotiates the transition.

So what the radius really means is that you're interested in data of roughly that accuracy - but the API *will not* guarantee that you get updates within that radius. You can think of it as Apple saying, "We're going to bucket your accuracy into one of 3 groups - but we didn't give you an enumeration, because we want to reserve the right to develop better methods of fixing your location without you having to change your code". Of course, in reality, any real app will change if they change their method of getting location, because they are *annoyingly* vague about this location stuff.

In other words, you will get a location fix *at* the cell tower with some totally made up guess as to how good that accuracy is; when you move to the next tower, you will instantly jump to *its* location, with a similarly fuzzy fix - does that make sense? CoreLocation is telling you you're *at* the cell tower with accuracy of however far the cell tower's signal reaches; as you move to another tower, you will probably get the bounciness of the handoff.

So when it comes to it, to really do a good job, you have to assume that the data is one of "great", "ok", or "bad" and use other methods - like [Kalmann filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) - if you really need to have a better guess at where the user is. As a zeroth-order approximation, I would just debounce the callbacks based on the *time* of the update, which is given, and assume that the user isn't really leaping kilometers back and forth within a few seconds, but rather, travelling in the direction of the first new update.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'd be better off, using a desiredAccuracy that is **smaller** than the radius of 300m, i.e. `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`. Have you tried that?
There is no documentation about the underlying logic, but I'd assume, that `desiredAccuracy` can be regarded as the **minimium** distance you'd have to travel that the movement counts as a "border crossing".
Region monitoring is based on "significant location events", not GPS – otherwise the battery wouldn't last half a day.

If you use such a high `desiredAccuracy`, the system might get more than one significant location event (these seem to be generated about every 500m – also depending how many wifi networks you have in the area.
In that case, the system might compare the current location resulting from the significant change with the distance to all sides of your region.
If you're just outside 1000m from opposite side of your region, it might notify again and only stop notifying once your outside the 1000m from **each side** of your region.

The reason for the accuracy parameter is rather to avoid border crossings, if you are too close to the border, so you're not seeing inside-outside-inside-outside etc while traveling just outside the border...

In my apps, I tried many many different combinations of radius and accuracy and settled on 500m/100m and 100m/10m – those work very well in my real work within-city szenario.

(see also the excellent article series http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/)

Comment: Interesting thought...I'll definitely try that out (and will upvote/accept if this is indeed the case, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet this is your issue, `locationManager:didExitRegion:` gets called for EVERY region that every location manager in every application on your iPhone has registered.  You need to compare the region's identifier string sent as a parameter with the region's identifier string of the region you want your app to currently do something with.

When you send `[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:1000];` you're creating a region, if it doesn't already exists to be monitored for. This is NOT the same as adding an observer to NSNotification Center. Apple's region object blindly sends the notification to EVERY CLLocationManager which then sends the message to the delegate.

Comment: Interesting theory, but I'm quite sure you're incorrect in saying that locationManager:didExitRegion: gets called for every region on every app -- as the docs (http://goo.gl/TvU7y) say, regions are a system-wide resource and are therefore limited; however, it is only with multiple CLLocationManagers in the same app that you could get multiple notifications. Additionally, checking the identifier property of a region is intended to be used instead of pointer-level equality checking, but not to ensure you're not getting app-external notifications.

Comment: You are correct, it is fired only in the active LocationManagers. But, it is fired every time any region in the SYSTEM is exited. I am certain that if you create two apps, run one startMonitoring for some region, quit the app, start another app that starts monitor for another region, the active LocationManager will fire the message to its delegate for BOTH regions (plus any others that other apps may have registered).

Answer (score 0):

First, the documentation does not indicate that desiredAccuracy alone determines how far out of a region you need to be, before didExitRegion event is generated. If you want to fine-tune how often events are fired, you need to use the distanceFilter as well, which determines the horizontal movement you need to have moved before an event will be fired.

If use of the distanceFilter does not work, then I would recommend the following:

1. If you are using NSNotificationCenter, then ensure that you have removed other classes from notification, via [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]. You can optionally specify a name and object to this call.
2. 1000 Km is a large radius, which has a high chance of intersecting with many regions in the vicinity. I would try a lower number for this parameter to see if that doesn't decrease the number of exit notifications that you are receiving. The only thing that indicates that this may not be the solution is that you did not say you are receiving blasts of didEnterRegion as well.
3. Lastly, I would check the identifier of the CLRegion being passed in the didExitRegionEvent, to see if you can't set up an NSDictionary of regions yourself. You'll have to set a region to the dictionary on didEnterRegion, and remove it on didExitRegion. So, on didExitRegion, all you have to do is ensure that you are interested in the region by checking that you have the region already. I would guess that CLRegion is already equipped with isEqual: and hash to allow it to be stored in a collection.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. However, about the distanceFilter, I just checked the docs and I don't see any (documented) relation between the distance filter and region monitoring. I'm not using NSNotificationCenter here, so that can't be it. BTW, the radius is expressed in meters, not km, so we're dealing with 1km here. About storing the CLRegions, the docs specify that you can only rely on the identifier for equality.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the identifier in an NSDictionary? It might seem a bit awkward keeping a map of the regions, but if you manage the size and release it appropriately, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in order to save battery you have to use `monitorForSignificantLocationChange`.
My solution is to filter out multiple alerts coming within 60 seconds for the same region:

```
-(BOOL)checkForMultipleNotifications:(GeoFenceModel*)fence
{
  GeoFenceModel *tempFence = [fenceAlertsTimeStamps objectForKey:fence.geoFenceId];
  if(tempFence == nil){
    fence.lastAlertDate = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    [fenceAlertsTimeStamps setObject:fence forKey:fence.geoFenceId];
    NSLog(@"checkForMultipleNotifications : no Notifications found for Region : %@, Adding to Dictionary with timestamp %.1f",fence.geoFenceId,fence.lastAlertDate.doubleValue);
  }
  else if(([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - fence.lastAlertDate.doubleValue) <= 60.0){
    NSLog(@"checkForMultipleNotifications : Multiple region break notifications within 60 seconds, skipping this alert");
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```